# Trying to set a device specific scale on an ActivityIndicator in Xamarin XAML causes a crash

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have a Xamarin.Forms app we are converting from code behind to XAML. I have already used `OnPlatform` successfully, but it is causing a crash when setting the scale of our ActivityIndicator. I am testing on the iOS simulator. Here's the code:

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" Color="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
      <ActivityIndicator.Scale>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:double" iOS="4.0" Android="3.0" />
      </ActivityIndicator.Scale>
    </ActivityIndicator>
```

In contrast, these two would work:

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" Color="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
      <ActivityIndicator.Scale>
        4.0
      </ActivityIndicator.Scale>
    </ActivityIndicator>
```

-

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" Color="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" Scale="4.0">
    </ActivityIndicator>
```

Comment: Could you share what's the crash log?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
<ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" Color="White"
HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
  <ActivityIndicator.Scale>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="4.0" Android="3.0" />
  </ActivityIndicator.Scale>
</ActivityIndicator>
```

it's a Type argument. double isn't really the type, Double is.

Answer (score 4):

Case sensitive on the Type:

Change:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:double" iOS="4.0" Android="3.0" />
```

To:

```
<OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" iOS="4.0" Android="3.0" />
```

FYI: Enable XAML compiling to catch these during compile time vs. run-time.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I read the accepted answer first, but your tip about XAML compiling is great